# How to find a Xpath and add value to the tags in Camel

Tags: java, string, xpath, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to find an Xpath from exchange body and add a value to the tag.

```
<root>
<details1>    
   <Name>Ying</Name>
   <status></status>
</details1>
<details2>    
   <Name>Ying</Name>
   <status></status>
</details2>
</root>
```

I want to find `xPath=root/details2/status` From this exchange body and add value to the status. Since there are two occurances of status in the body String I will not be able to use `String1.replace('<status></status>',<status>no</status>)` Is there any way to use camel Xpath to find the correct tag and add the value?

Comment: Isn't easier to use an XML parser like jackson in a processor to find and the set value?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti I'm writing a Generic code and I don't have a specific pojo to map. Exchange body will be a String.

Comment: You don't need a a pojo. Just convert your exchange to a string and pass it to bean and let jackson handle the rest and set the resulting string back to the exchange.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti that's something which I never tried. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

With xpath you can  find and read the correct tag. But how are you going to write it?
One solution could be to use the xpath inside an xlst tranformation.
So you can add the value you want to put in the element in a camel header "myHeader" and then use it in the xslt as an xsl:param .

Assuming the xml is in the inbox folder then

```
 from("file:inbox?noop=true")
 .setHeader("myHeader",constant("no"))
 .to("xslt:mytransform.xslt")
 .to("file:outbox/?fileName=out.xml");
```

Will put the value "no" in root/details2/status.

Where mytransform.xlst  inside your /src/main/resources folder is like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="myHeader"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/details2/status[. = '']">
        <status><xsl:value-of select="$myHeader"/></status>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Xpath /root/details2/status[. = ''] matches empty status elements